# How to interpolate datetimes for a given interval quickly?

Tags: c#

Say I have been given 12/25/1995 12:00:00 and 12/25/2005 12:00:00 and I want every datetime every 5 seconds between these two dates. Is there a way to do this quickly (say in less than half a second)? I have been doing a normal foreach loop and adding the interval in seconds until it is equal to the end time, but that obviously takes way too long.

Comment: how do you want them? do you want to work with them right away or?

Comment: Why do you want them? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: you want 63 million ish DateTimes?

Comment: Use timer instead and set the interval you want.

Comment: DateTimes are a pretty simple structure. Take a look at how they store their data. Try and figure out an offset that would require the least amount of conversion and add it instead (for example 5000 ms or 5,000,000 micro seconds). Like everyone else, I'm curious why you want to do this. Where are you going to put them, that's where you'll be spending your time. And, doing anything 63 MM times will take a while, but. If you can shave off a few instructions you might see a difference

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would probably do it (this returns the values *between* the start and end, but not including them, though it would be simple to modify it to include them as well):

```
public static List<DateTime> GetRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, TimeSpan interval)
{
    // Set the initial size of the list to avoid dynamic resizing during 'Add' operations
    int itemCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(end - start).Ticks / interval.Ticks + 2);
    var result = new List<DateTime>(itemCount);

    while ((start = start.Add(interval)) < end) result.Add(start);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others pointed out in comments are you sure you want all of them at once?

This will let you iterate over the dates without necessarily projecting them all at once (until you do something like .Select() or .ToArray()):

```cs
void Main()
{
    var start = DateTime.Parse("12/25/1995 12:00:00");
    var end = DateTime.Parse("12/25/2005 12:00:00");
    var interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5d);

    var total = EnumerateDateTimeIntervals(start, end, interval).Count();
}

IEnumerable<DateTime> EnumerateDateTimeIntervals(DateTime start, DateTime end, TimeSpan interval)
{
    var current = start;
    do
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.Add(interval);
    } while (current.CompareTo(end) <= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it on my machine in < 500ms.

```
     var sw = new Stopwatch();
 var ticksPerFiveSeconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks;
 sw.Start();
 var b = new DateTime();
 var p = new DateTime(1995, 12, 25, 12, 00, 00);
 var end = new DateTime(2005, 12, 25, 12, 00, 00);
 var size = (int)((end - p).TotalSeconds / 5 + 1);
 // preallocate array.
 var times = new DateTime[size];
 int i = 0;
 long ticks = p.Ticks;
 while ( i < size )
 {
     times[i] = b.AddTicks(ticks);
     ticks += ticksPerFiveSeconds;
     i++;
 }
 sw.Stop();
 Console.WriteLine($"{(decimal)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000M} {times.Length} {times.Last()}");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the best one in my machine is `ticks` it took 1100ms

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
var ticksPerFiveSeconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks; 
//DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5).Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks; will aslo return the same value
var twentyYearsFromNow = today.AddYears(20);
var todayTicks = today.Ticks;
var twentyYearsFromNowTicks = twentyYearsFromNow.Ticks;
var listofdate = new List<DateTime>();
var timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
while (todayTicks <= twentyYearsFromNowTicks)
{
    listofdate.Add(new DateTime(todayTicks));
    todayTicks = todayTicks + ticksPerFiveSeconds;
}
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("ticks :" + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: What about `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks`?

Comment: @John I havent look at it, will do and expand if it is better

Comment: I just find `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).Ticks` to be more explicit in what you're trying to do. I didn't expect it to perform differently.

Comment: `timer.Interval` is the time between timer executions, and not the total time spent doing something. You should use `var timer = new Stopwatch();` and `Console.WriteLine("ticks :" + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);` instead. The code above runs in `1.868` seconds on my machine.

Comment: This method averaged 940.0ms on my machine, and Rufus' averaged 909.7ms. I tested them using Benchmark.NET for the same date range and interval as OP suggested.

Comment: @John, i guess Rufus answer is better

Comment: @John, hahaha, i was suppose to do a *,* but instead i pressed *.* :D :D